# Strange margin issue on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, layout

I'm getting strange issue on ipad when I visit my demo site, basically player seems to be shifted to the top, this is how it looks on iPad (ipad Mini iOS 6.1, tested in chrome and safari):

[image]

and this is demo site (change screen resolution to ipad size): http://freshbeer.lv/test/index.html
It works perfectly fine on mac and pc, just some issues with ipad, and I assume smartphones as well ;/ Can you suggest what is causing this problem?

Comment: Your link to your website isn't working, so no one can help atm :/

Comment: if this is the only reason for voting down. please undo it and just add a comment instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `reset.css`, `display: inline-block` is applied to `<audio>`. Remove it. Also remove `margin: 0 !important;` from `.audiojs .scrubber, .audiojs .scrubber:hover` (Lines 442, 447)

Comment: Tried applying different values for margins and paddings from top, didn't see any change, could you please specify exactly what do you mean?

Comment: removed display: inline-block; for audio, as well as margins, didn't work, also added rule audio {display: block;} still nothing, did it work for you? I'm testing on ipad mini, maybe there is something specific for it?

Comment: I can't debug on iOS. Looks to me like `.scrubber`has a margin when it shouldn't. Try commenting out `.scrubber:hover` and `.audiojs .scrubber`, and `.audiojs .scrubber:hover`. (Lines 300, 439, & 443)

Comment: Commented out all scrubber stuff, still getting this same error... omg why is that? Also, you might be confusing .scrubber with .audiojs, scrubber is that black progress bar, which is actually in correct position, .audiojs is that dark tray player container, which seems to have strange margin at the bottom, however play button and timer (which are inside .audiojs) are actually at right place.

Comment: What if you move `.scrubber` before `.play-pause` in the HTML?

Comment: @Mooseman probably not something you would like to here, but again doesn't fix it.. This is very very strange, it works fine on my android device, just iPod (and I assume iphone) give this sort of strange appearance.

Comment: What if you add `overflow: hidden` to `.audiojs`? Since the text and play icon still show outside the box, I would think that may be the problem.